# Celery with Supervisord workers are not working Isolated

Tags: django, python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery, supervisord

.conf file

```
[program:task1]
    directory=/home/ubuntu/proj1
    command=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A proj1 worker -l info --concurrency=10 -n proj1_worker@%%h
    user=ubuntu
    numprocs=1
    stdout_logfile=/var/log/proj1_celeryd.log
    stderr_logfile=/var/log/proj1_celeryd.log
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    startsecs=10
    stopwaitsecs=600
    priority=998

[program:task2]
    directory=/home/ubuntu/proj2/
    command=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A proj2 worker -l info --concurrency=10 -n proj2_worker@%%h
    user=ubuntu
    numprocs=1
    stdout_logfile=/var/log/proj2_celeryd.log
    stderr_logfile=/var/log/proj2_celeryd.log
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    startsecs=10
    stopwaitsecs=600
    priority=998

[group:celeryworkers]
programs=task1,task2
```

proj1_worker and proj2_worker are not getting isolated.
At first, always proj1_worker is called even I called proj2_worker

I don't know where I am going wrong. Kindly assist.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which broker do you use? RabbitMQ, Redis,...?

Comment: RabbitMQ broker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I really recommend you to use `virtualenv` for each project. Create 2 separate virtualenvs (you can specify your own location), see https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html.

```
python3 -m venv /home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/proj1
python3 -m venv /home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/proj2
```

Activate virtualenv and install celery:

```
source /home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/proj1/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade celery

source /home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/proj2/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade celery
```

Your supervisor configuration should then look like this:

```
[program:task1]
    directory=/home/ubuntu/proj1
    command=/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/proj1/bin/celery worker -A proj1 -l info --concurrency=10 -n proj1_worker@%%h
    # ...

[program:task2]
    directory=/home/ubuntu/proj2
    command=/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/proj1/bin/celery worker -A proj2 -l info --concurrency=10 -n proj2_worker@%%h
    # ...
```

Next, create 2 separate virtual hosts for your projects:

```
rabbitmqctl add_user proj_1 <PASSWORD>
rabbitmqctl add_vhost proj_1_vhost
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p proj_1_vhost proj_1 ".*" ".*" ".*"

rabbitmqctl add_user proj_2 <PASSWORD>
rabbitmqctl add_vhost proj_2_vhost
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p proj_2_vhost proj_2 ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

Finally modify celery configuration to use newly created virtual hosts:

```
app = Celery('proj1_celery_app')
app.conf.update(
    # ...
    broker_url='amqp://proj1:<PASSWORD>@localhost:5672/proj_1_vhost'
    # ...
)

app = Celery('proj2_celery_app')
app.conf.update(
    # ...
    broker_url='amqp://proj2:<PASSWORD>@localhost:5672/proj_2_vhost'
    # ...
)
```

For more info about rabbit vhosts see this SO post: [Running multiple instances of celery on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200532/running-multiple-instances-of-celery-on-the-same-server).

Comment: hey, thanks for your step by step answer.is it work in production?